# I'm Having many problems after last update, can anybody help me?

Tags: updates, lubuntu

I'm using Lubuntu 14.04 and since last update I got the exactly same software update screen a few times now. Pcmanfm is unchecked and I cannot check it. Also I cannot open synaptics package manager anymore and when I make a new panel pcmanfm crashes and I have to restart my computer. Lxappearence also doesn't have openbox opions anymore.  Can anybody help me here? I have no idea what to do.[image]

Comment: Try updating all the other packages in that list.

Comment: How come you have kernel 3.19? `uname -r` gives me `3.13.0-65-generic`.

Comment: @DKBose `linux-image-generic-lts-vivid` is the newer kernel for the 14.04 LTS releases.  Updating is not a requirement but it gives 3.19.x

Answer (score 0):

Run `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade in the terminal`  That should enable you to download and install all upgrades that are available.

Comment: For kernel upgrades, `dist-upgrade`, not plain `upgrade`, maybe needed.